# How to count the total of records and show in a separate column in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable in C#, where I have a monthly report Like this:

[image]

I have just shown 4 dates as of now. **All these date come from a PIVOT Table in SQL**. Whereas, **I have added the Totals column programmatically.**

What I want is I want to count the  number of A's, B's, and C's in **Total A's**, **Total B's**, and **Total C's** Field.

This is what I tried so far

```
  DataTable report = DataAccess.GetDataInDataTable(ConstantFieldsModel.PRIMARYCONNECTION, "usp_GetReport", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param);
  report.Columns.Add("Total As", typeof(int)).SetOrdinal(2);// adds 'Total' field at position 5
  report.Columns.Add("Total Bs", typeof(int)).SetOrdinal(3);
  report.Columns.Add("Total Cs", typeof(int)).SetOrdinal(4);
  foreach (DataRow row in report.Rows)
  {
      int sum = 0;
      foreach (DataColumn col in report.Columns)
      {
          if (!row.IsNull(col))
          {
             string val = row[col].ToString();
             int a;
             if (int.TryParse(val, out a))
             {
                sum += a;
              }
            }
    }
    row.SetField("Total", sum);
  }
```

I get no errors, but the Total shows the Ids of each record which is **NOT** what I want. (I know the **Total** Field is at the beginning, but this is because I have a month report to avoid scrolling just to see the total, I have added it in the front.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in the edit, what is the total column? the image has 3, none of which "shows the ids"?

Comment: @MarcGravell, I have edited the requirement now.

Comment: You are summing only numeric values and there is only one on each row, the Id. You should probably restrict the count to look for specific _string_ values ("A", "B" or "C")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have added the Totals column programmatically.

So: keep hold of these columns you have added:

```cs
List<DataColumn> myTotals = new List<DataColumn>();\
// and .Add when you create each column
```

Now, instead of looking at all columns:

```cs
foreach (DataColumn col in report.Columns)
```

**just look at these 3**

```cs
foreach (DataColumn col in myTotals)
```

If you declared them as being of type `int`, you can probably avoid a format/parse step, too:

```cs
sum += (int)row[col];
```